# How to move linux executables to a ramdisk?

Tags: linux, node.js, ramdisk

i've made a ramdisk this way:

```
mkdir -p /media/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /media/ramdisk/
```

The reason for this is because i run a lot of node.js scripts and their execution time is very small, but i suspect that the time overhead is because it reloads the node.js executable from disk and destroys it on each subsecuent run.
So i think this might be the solution to gain a bit, if not much, performance.
How can i move a program like node to the ramdisk and run it from there? The idea is to have a startup script that creates the ramdisk and puts the node files inside of it.
Note that i'm currently using fedora 16 for what's it's worth.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file contents are probably already cached in RAM if they're accessed frequently, as ErikA explained.  But node.js probably still has to *parse* the JavaScript code each time.  That's a matter of CPU time, not disk access.

Answer (score 5):

If the scripts are being read frequently, they will reside in the kernel's read cache, and thus are already being read from memory.

Comment: The scripts are not written into disk, they exist as the input to node.js

Comment: Regardless, if they are accessed by *anything* on the system, they will be in the kernel's read cache.